# How to locate all resources in classpath with a specified name?

Tags: java

I want to list all files with a specific name in the class path. I am expecting multiple occurrences, hence `Class.getResource(String)` will not work.

Basically I have to identify all files with a specific name (ex: xyz.properties) anywhere in the class path and then read the metadata in them cumulatively.

I want something of the effect `Collection<URL> Class.getResources(String)` but could not find anything similar.

PS: I don't have the luxury of using any third party libraries, hence in need of a home grown solution.

Comment: this similar question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730580/how-to-read-several-resource-files-with-the-same-name-from-different-jars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Enumeration getResources(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) on the class loader to achieve the same.

For example:

```
Enumeration<URL> enumer = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("/Path/To/xyz.properties");
while (enumer.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.print(enumer.nextElement());
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example how the OP should be using that. He wants to find all resources that match a pattern in the classpath. Just giving a link is IMO not sufficient as an answer.

Comment: `ClassLoader#findResources()` is `protected`.

Comment: @maba Thanks, I stay corrected. Guess I wasn't paying close attention to the API docs. BTW usage is pretty straightforward, but anyways I will edit my answer with a usage.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is I read java source files from classpath and process them using [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). I am using follwing code :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

assert (classLoader != null);

// pkgName = "com.comp.pkg"
String path = pkgName.replace('.', '/');

// resources will contain all java files and sub-packages
Enumeration<URL> resources = classLoader.getResources(path);

 if(resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL resource = resources.nextElement();     
        File directory = new File(resource.getFile());
        // .. process file, check this directory for properties files
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers that propose using `ClassLoader.getResources(String)` only work if the "name" in question is the full path of the resource. As the methods's javadoc states, "*The name of a resource is a `/`-separated **path** name that identifies the resource.*" It's unfortunate and misleading that the parameter is called "name" instead of "path."

For those who, like me, are really looking for all resources with a given (simple) name - without knowing the full path of the resource - the current answers won't work. @NandkumarTekale's code example states "*resources will contain all java files and sub-packages*" in the comments, but unfortunately that is not true. Nor does it make any difference to use `ClassLoader.findResources(String)` (which is indeed protected in the `ClassLoader` class itself, but pulled into the public API by concrete subclasses like `URLClassLoader`, which in turn serves as the base class for most commonly used class loaders).

The most straightforward solution that I could find uses the [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) library:

```
try (ScanResult result = new ClassGraph().acceptClasspathElementsContainingResourcePath("*/html5.dtd").scan())
{
    System.err.println(result.getResourcesWithLeafName("html5.dtd").getURLs());
}
```

Sadly, this clashes with the OP's request for a solution without the use of third-party libraries. However, ClassGraph's source code is available on GitHub and can be used as an inspiration for a "home grown" solution. In broad strokes, one would have to find the class loader's base URLs (e.g., using `URLClassLoader.getURLs()`) and then write URL-specific code for searching the contents of each URL (e.g., if it's a `jar:file:`... URL, load the JAR and iterate over its contents, or if it's a `file:`... URL use `java.io.File` to explore the folder contents). There are *a lot* of special cases to consider, though (e.g., OSGi class loaders), and a truly general solution would probably replicate a fair amount of what ClassGraph does under the hood. If it is valid to assume that the resources will, for example, always be packaged in a JAR (or always as plain files in the file system), a more tailored solution could be created for just those cases.