# getResourceAsStream returns a stream to the first matching file

Tags: java, resourcebundle

In my application, several libraries are assembled.
Whenever those libraries comes with resources having a same name, `getResourceAsStream("myfile")` seems to return a stream to whatever file come first.
This is true for any file, including Resource bundles.

In the following example, a [library with a MyMibrary class](https://github.com/lgvr123/mygroup_mylibrary) has a file called "config.properties". And does

```
InputStream is = MyLibrary.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")
```

When called in a standalone context, the right config file is used.

But when loaded as a dependency from an [application](https://github.com/lgvr123/mygroup_myapplication) having its own "config.properties", the same statement returns the config file **of the application** instead of the one of the library.

The same applies also for ResourceBundles (which is using `getResourceAsStream` too) :
If both the library and the application are using Resource bundles named the same way, when called from the application, the library will be using the application resource bundle instead of its own.

My question is how to instruct `getResourceAsStream` (especially in the context of Resource bundle loading) to use the right resource ?

EDIT: this question differs partially from [How to read several resource files with the same name from different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730580/how-to-read-several-resource-files-with-the-same-name-from-different-jars) in the way the latter question deals only with resources while my question deals also with **ResourceBundles**.

Comment: Partially. See my comment in the proposed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `getResources`. Note the plural. Unfortunately, whilst `MyLibrary.class.getResource` is right, class does not have the `getResources` method copied over from `ClassLoader`. So, you do have to go via classloader. This is annoying, because in admittedly exotic (Agents, bootstrap classes) situations, `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` will be `null`, so then you need to write code to defer to the system loader instead. For bonus annoyance, the method predates iterators, so it returns an `Enumeration` instead.

Thus, the full treatment:

```
ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
if (cl == null) cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
var resources = cl.getResources("config.properties"); // No slash! See footnote 1
while (resources.hasNextElement()) {
  URL resource = resources.nextElement();
  try (var in = resource.openStream()) {
    // yay we can read it now!
  }
}
```

In admittedly really exotic context

[1] Loading via the classloader already starts at the classloader's root, so the leading slash is not required. In fact, if you use it, it'll fail. So, `MyClass.class.getLoader().getResource("foo")` is the same as `MyClass.class.getResource("/foo")`, except that the first snippet fails in agent/bootstrap situations.

Comment: The limitation is that this doesn't apply to ResourceBundle, because the `ResourceBundle.Control` class is explicitly calling `is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)` meaning that it is not able to detect the right resource bundle to use. I guess a solution would be to override `ResourceBundle.Control` by a subclass using that technic to identify the right resource bundle ?

Comment: Yup, if code you didn't write does the wrong thing, you either stop making it to the wrong thing, fork it, or hack it.